# When do the threads in python die if the method thread.stop() or thread.join() is not called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

**Here is a snippet of code:**

```
def display():
  threading.Timer(1,display).start()
  print("Number")
display()
```

For this code I want to ask the following things:

1. Every second new thread spawns, is that right?
2. Every second the last thread dies because the function executes completely so the older thread dies, is that right? If not then what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Timer` derives from `Thread`, so yes: many threads are started.
2. Threads die when their invoked functions return (or throw) whether or not you call `join`, but **resources** reserved for them may or may not be reclaimed until you do.  (Note that threads are roots in common garbage-collection schemes, so it’s unwise to rely on dropping references to `Thread` objects.)

Comment: So there is a chance that i can run out of resources if I don't join them?

Comment: @S.Chirag: At least in some implementations.  I *think* CPython doesn’t leak in that case, but it’s usually very easy to `join` every thread.  Here, you can just store the previous `Timer` and `join` it after starting the next.