# How to end Threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a function `text_to_speach` that receives a text and speak it with `gtts` module:

```
def text_to_speach(text):
    try:
        tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='fr', tld="com", slow=False)
        tts.save("audio.mp3")  
        playsound.playsound('audio.mp3', False)
        os.remove('audio.mp3')
    except:
        print('Check Speak issue !!!')
```

That function runs inside a Thread:

```
def speak(reply):
    thread = Thread(target=text_to_speach, args=(reply,), daemon=True)
    thread.start()
```

Now every time I run the `speak()` function it creates a `Thread`
and I don't want it to create multiple Threads.

So I want every time I run `speak` function the **Thread will end** after that.

Example:

```
speak("some text")
#Thread end

speak("some text 2")
#Thread end

speak("some text 3")
#Thread end
```

So my question is how to end the thread?

Comment: Thread will already end when the function returns... What exactly is your question?

Comment: i'm new to Threads so i don't know hwo they works, so do you mean when the function is finished the Theads will end !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes. [When do the threads in python die if the method thread.stop() or thread.join() is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916471/when-do-the-threads-in-python-die-if-the-method-thread-stop-or-thread-join-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking solution:

```py
def speak(reply):
    thread = Thread(target=text_to_speach, args=(reply,), daemon = True)
    thread.start()
    thread.join() # it will block till thread ends
```

Comment: But I think that there's some other elegant solution..

Comment: Sounds exactly was OP ask for.